# Array of 400 ints

Tags: java, arrays

Why doesn't Netbeans like this?

```
int[] newArray = new int[400];
newArray = {8,2,22,97,...,48};
```

Comment: _why doesn't Netbeans like this_ , what do you mean

Comment: It isn't Netbeans' fault that you're using illegal Java syntax.

Comment: *"Why doesn't Netbeans like this?"*  <pun>Maybe Netbeans is Arrayist.</pun>

Comment: Note, OP, that if you fixed your second line with `newArray = new int[] {8,22,97,..}`, you'd be creating **two arrays** but only keeping the latter one assigned. The first one would immediately be released to the garbage collector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do like below as you can do this kind of **assignment during initialization only**.

Also note, **there is no dimension parameter required(allowed) in this case**

```
    int[] newArray = new int[]{8,2,22,97,38,15,0,40,0,75,4,5,7,78,52,12,50,77,91,8,49,49,99,40,17,81,18,57,60,87,17,40,98,43,69,48,4,56,62,0,81,49,31,73,55,79,14,29,93,71,40,67,53,88,30,3,49,13,36,65,52,70,95,23,4,60,11,42,69,24,68,56,1,32,56,71,37,2,36,91,22,31,16,71,51,67,63,89,41,92,36,54,22,40,40,28,66,33,13,80,24,47,32,60,99,3,45,2,44,75,33,53,78,36,84,20,35,17,12,50,32,98,81,28,64,23,67,10,26,38,40,67,59,54,70,66,18,38,64,70,67,26,20,68,2,62,12,20,95,63,94,39,63,8,40,91,66,49,94,21,24,55,58,5,66,73,99,26,97,17,78,78,96,83,14,88,34,89,63,72,21,36,23,9,75,0,76,44,20,45,35,14,0,61,33,97,34,31,33,95,78,17,53,28,22,75,31,67,15,94,3,80,4,62,16,14,9,53,56,92,16,39,5,42,96,35,31,47,55,58,88,24,0,17,54,24,36,29,85,57,86,56,0,48,35,71,89,7,5,44,44,37,44,60,21,58,51,54,17,58,19,80,81,68,5,94,47,69,28,73,92,13,86,52,17,77,4,89,55,40,4,52,8,83,97,35,99,16,7,97,57,32,16,26,26,79,33,27,98,66,88,36,68,87,57,62,20,72,3,46,33,67,46,55,12,32,63,93,53,69,4,42,16,73,38,25,39,11,24,94,72,18,8,46,29,32,40,62,76,36,20,69,36,41,72,30,23,88,34,62,99,69,82,67,59,85,74,4,36,16,20,73,35,29,78,31,90,1,74,31,49,71,48,86,81,16,23,57,5,54,1,70,54,71,83,51,54,69,16,92,33,48,61,43,52,1,89,19,67,48};
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "but why doesn't Netbeans like this?".

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much. Been googling for ages. Guess i've been staring at code for too long today. Thanks again.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I added a brief description in the top.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I think I did that before seeing your comment. Any way thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Agree! but personally will not advice as doesn't look good syntactically.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign an array that way. Instead, you should use the proper initialization syntax:

```
int[] newArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4,...};
```

NetBeans is complaining because `newArray = {1,2,3,4,...}` is bad syntax.

Comment: This does answer the question (only one so far).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this syntax?

```
        int[] newArray = new int[] {8,2,22,97,38,15,0,40,0,75,4,5,7,78,52,12,50,77,91,8,49,49,99,40,17,81,18,57,60,87,17,40,98,43,69,48,4,56,62,0,81,49,31,73,55,79,14,29,93,71,40,67,53,88,30,3,49,13,36,65,52,70,95,23,4,60,11,42,69,24,68,56,1,32,56,71,37,2,36,91,22,31,16,71,51,67,63,89,41,92,36,54,22,40,40,28,66,33,13,80,24,47,32,60,99,3,45,2,44,75,33,53,78,36,84,20,35,17,12,50,32,98,81,28,64,23,67,10,26,38,40,67,59,54,70,66,18,38,64,70,67,26,20,68,2,62,12,20,95,63,94,39,63,8,40,91,66,49,94,21,24,55,58,5,66,73,99,26,97,17,78,78,96,83,14,88,34,89,63,72,21,36,23,9,75,0,76,44,20,45,35,14,0,61,33,97,34,31,33,95,78,17,53,28,22,75,31,67,15,94,3,80,4,62,16,14,9,53,56,92,16,39,5,42,96,35,31,47,55,58,88,24,0,17,54,24,36,29,85,57,86,56,0,48,35,71,89,7,5,44,44,37,44,60,21,58,51,54,17,58,19,80,81,68,5,94,47,69,28,73,92,13,86,52,17,77,4,89,55,40,4,52,8,83,97,35,99,16,7,97,57,32,16,26,26,79,33,27,98,66,88,36,68,87,57,62,20,72,3,46,33,67,46,55,12,32,63,93,53,69,4,42,16,73,38,25,39,11,24,94,72,18,8,46,29,32,40,62,76,36,20,69,36,41,72,30,23,88,34,62,99,69,82,67,59,85,74,4,36,16,20,73,35,29,78,31,90,1,74,31,49,71,48,86,81,16,23,57,5,54,1,70,54,71,83,51,54,69,16,92,33,48,61,43,52,1,89,19,67,48};
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The question asked covers up the more important question, *How do I initialize an array of 400 ints with a static array initialization list*. :-)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik why is new int[] redundant, isn't that mandatory syntax?

Comment: @JeroenVuurens `int[] newArray = {8,2,22,...}` is legal and, at least as far as I am concerned, the preferred syntax.

Comment: thanks, you're right. Thought you could only do that when defining class vars.